# Name of class, action and controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

in the mvc web application url

http://www.myserver.com/movies/titles/19

I think the name of the action is 'titles'

The name of the controller is 'movies'

but which of the items is the class from the url?

Comment: What do you mean by "class"?

Comment: like the class in the web application when coding

Comment: Your controller is the name of the class.

Comment: You don't have such thing, the only thing that you have is a controller which in your case it's name is movieController

Comment: Technically the full name of the controller is MoviesController.

Comment: thank you for all of the help guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using any one of the default templates from Asp.Net MVC (assuming routes are setup correctly) then:

> http://www.myserver.com/movies/titles/19

and assuming:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "Default", 
  "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  new { controller = "Home", 
        action = "Index", 
        id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

The controller would look like:

```
//  Controller class and 'name'
public class MoviesController
{
  public ActionResult Titles (int id)
  {
    // id = 19 with the example above

    return View();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no hard rule what the parts of the URL has to be, but with the default routes the name of the controller would be `MoviesController` and the name of the action method would be `Titles`.

It's usual for an action to use a view, which would also have the name `Titles` unless you specify something else. The view has a model, and if that model is defined as a specific type in the view header, it would usually be something like `TitlesModel`.

But those are all conventions, you could add a route that matches that URL and specifies a different controller and action if you like. The action could do whatever it likes to return a response, it doesn't actually have to use a view at all.